# Validator text too long. Only parts of it showing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add validation too my password text form field in my app in flutter. The problem is that my validator text is too long so only parts of it shows on the screen. Is there any way to make the text form field below it automatically slide down so the whole validation text is shown?

The text form fields are placed in a column inside a form.

Appreciate any help,
Cheers!

Comment: Do you want to increase textfild horizontally or vertically if it gets increased?

Comment: I'd prefer vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you.

```
     TextFormField(
                maxLines: null,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                validator: (value) {
                  print(value);
                  return null;
                },
              ),
```